# Google Account sign-in error (two-factor authentication)

Tags: android, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I'm using Google two-factor authentication on a Galaxy 10.1 tab and receiving notification of a "Sign-in error" for my Google account.

gmail and other Google apps seemed to be working, but I went to the security settings for my account on a different computer ("2-step verification") and revoked the application-specific password for tablet. I then created a new one.

The new password works for gmail, gtalk and other Google apps on the tablet, but I still receive the notification of sign-in error.

I thought it might be one of the apps on the tablet where I'd granted access to my Google account, but couldn't find the culprit. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device to review log file, compare with "Connected Sites, Apps, and Services")

Can someone point me to where on the tablet I might be able to track down which app has the problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is limited to programming questions, you'd be better asking this question on android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

Click this link below, and login your gmail account.https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en&hide_authsub=1

Configure "Application-specific passwords" for you android, write a name like "My Android",
and press the "generator password" button. and you see a random password.

Login your android gmail with the random password. Then everything is ok.

reference:
http://www.techworld.com.au/article/407756/how_fix_two-factor_authentication_log-in_error_gmail_android/

Comment: This is the solution until they fix the bug.  It worked...  I have 2FA enabled, maybe the device did not support it.  I could still generate a strong password with the link and it let me in.

Comment: This worked for me, I have another device (new one) that logged in without the need for this, so probably if your device is old like mine, then you're going to need to setup this new app-specific password.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question about finding the application, but for what it's worth, seems like the problem was caused by a very recent update from Google, so my best bet would be to wait for them to fix it. I'm getting it on my phone too, and numerous other people are reporting the same issue: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=28013031

Comment: thanks for the link - it seems spot on. I was trying to figure how I'd reframe the question in a programming way (more appropriate to StackOverflow). Something along the lines of "I can iterate over the installed apps on my phone in my own app--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598769/list-of-user-installed-apps--but what datastore on Android might contain error text for the situation I described. Anyway, thanks again for the link.